# Generic Provisioning Profile creation

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

i need some tutorial links that describes the creation of generic provisiong profile for development or distribution.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Bettor question for the Apple SE site, or the Apple Developer Forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html
- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-apple-development-provisioning-pr.html
- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone
- http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237
- http://iphonetesters.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/testing-iphone-applications-basic-steps/
- http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/iphone/howto-iphone-application-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a provisioning profile that can be used across a suite of applications what you need to do is create a wildcard app id.

However, there are some limitations to using wildcards such as not being able to use gamecenter functionality.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2) for complete instructions